# How can i maintain side image icons through the app?

Tags: android, xml, sidebar, android-image

![enter image description here][1]i am developing the Android XML file .in my main XML we have 5 services image icons .if i am click on the one the one service icon the corresponding services XML is opening .but my need is the corresponding XML having the 5 services images in left side of the XML file how can i do it .please see my image and how can i do in the Android

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use fragments (one for the buttons, another for the content).
You can include a buttonbar xml in your layout xml files, make sure you have the right configurations for both landscape and portrait.
You can use ActionBar, and ActionBar Compat for pre-3.0 devices.

ActionbarCompat: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ActionBarCompat/index.html

Include: http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/02/25/android-layout-trick-2-include-to-reuse/

Comment: please see my added image how can i achive